# Different screen resolution in css

Tags: css

Hello everyone I'm new at CSS. My question is how can I make my design compatible with different screen resolution. By the way I have checked wc3 validator there is no error. I define a div tag which is for displaying my page with different resolution here is my tag:

```
.page {
    width: 964px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height:990px;
    background-image:url(../images/shadow.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
}
```

I mean when I look my website with 17" screen, my page is appeared different than 19" screen

Comment: Do you mean that the `width` and `height` of div should be same for all types of resolutions?

Comment: You have to write media query into css

Comment: Yes @Mr_Green For example when I look my website with 17" screen my page is appeared different than 19" screen

Comment: @Teodoris: You'll be targeting resolutions and pixel ratios, the size of the physical screen is irrelavant

Comment: Can you be more specific about *what looks different*? That is, *in what way* does it appear different?

Answer (score 3):

You will want to search for Responsive Designs CSS, you can either make the design use all percentage amounts for sizing, or create style sheets for specific resolutions.

Have a look at:

[Responsive Wire Frames](http://www.thismanslife.co.uk/projects/lab/responsivewireframes/)

Answer (score 2):

You can achive with CSS 3 media queries

Also check [Responsive Design and Techniques](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/08/10/techniques-for-gracefully-degrading-media-queries/) for media queries

Comment: The seminal work also is available at: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/