# How to make my web pages to look good in all different resolutions/monitors

Tags: html, css, web

When I run my web project on my laptop with a 15.6" screen, it looks good. However it looks different and bad in any other monitors, for example, a 22" monitor.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." — http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Check out existing question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640129/different-screen-resolution-in-css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Media queries](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries) are good for responsive web design. There are lots of tutorials on the web.

Comment: yes i know.. and i have already read most of them. But i still do not have a exact solution.. Some of them advice felixible-layout, some of them advice fixed-layout. Even though i tried to do some of them i still have same problem.

Comment: @Emilla You need to provide an example of what you have and what you want. Add a JS fiddle.